# Trouble with Facebook multi-level json php foreach loop

Tags: php, arrays, json, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I know questions like this one have been asked many times before. But believe me, I have SEARCHED without getting an answer peculiar to my problem.

I'm trying to get information from a json response I got from facebook graph api, using php.

the response looks like this:

```
{
  "albums": {
"data": [
  {
    "id": "1111111111111111111111111111", 
    "created_time": "2015-02-27T22:46:22+0000", 
    "photos": {
      "data": [
        {
          "name": "wedding", 
          "source": "https://scontent.xx.fbcdn.net/hphotos-xpf1/v/t1.0-9/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx", 
          "created_time": "2015-02-27T22:46:28+0000", 
          "id": "1111111111111111111111111111"
        }, 
        {
          "source": "https://scontent.xx.fbcdn.net/hphotos-xpf1/v/t1.0-9/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx", 
          "created_time": "2015-02-27T22:47:03+0000", 
          "id": "1111111111111111111111111111"
        }, 
        {
          "source": "https://fbcdn-sphotos-e-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-xfp1/v/t1.0-9/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx", 
          "created_time": "2015-02-27T22:47:10+0000", 
          "id": "1111111111111111111111111111"
        }, 
        {
          "name": "Shells", 
          "source": "https://fbcdn-sphotos-g-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-xap1/v/t1.0-9/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx", 
          "created_time": "2015-02-28T00:09:45+0000", 
          "id": "1111111111111111111111111111"
        }
      ], 
      "paging": {
        "cursors": {
          "before": "MTU5NjUyNDQzMzkxMDkwNQ==", 
          "after": "MTU5NjU0MDcwMzkwOTI3OA=="
        }
      }
    }
  }, 
  {
    "id": "1111111111111111666111111111", 
    "created_time": "2015-02-27T22:35:44+0000", 
    "photos": {
      "data": [
        {
          "source": "https://scontent.xx.fbcdn.net/hphotos-xpf1/v/t1.0-9/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx", 
          "created_time": "2015-02-27T22:35:46+0000", 
          "id": "111111111111111111111111333"
        }
      ], 
      "paging": {
        "cursors": {
          "before": "MTU5NjUyMjU1NzI0NDQyNg==", 
          "after": "MTU5NjUyMjU1NzI0NDQyNg=="
        }
      }
    }
  }
], 
"paging": {
  "cursors": {
    "after": "MTU5NjUyMjU1MDU3Nzc2MA==", 
    "before": "MTU5NjUyNDQwNzI0NDI0MQ=="
  }
}
}, 
"id": "76577536756346436343434"
 }
```

The problem is; the response has like 2 levels data arrays.
I need to get "source" and "name" from the "photos" "data" array.

This is what I've done:

```
<?php
$fbpageid = "I HAVE A VALID PAGE ID I USED HERE";
$fbaccess_token = "I HAVE A VALID ACCESS TOKEN I USED HERE";
$fburl = "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.2/{$fbpageid}?fields=albums{photos{name,source}}&access_token={$fbaccess_token}";
/***I ENTERED THIS URL ABOVE INTO MY BROWSER WITH ALL THE VARIABLES CORRECT, IT WORKED FINE.. ..GAVE ME A RESPONSE LIKE THE ONE ABOVE**/

$fbfetch = file_get_contents($fburl); /***FROM MY PREVIOUS INSTAGRAM PROJECTS, I KNOW THIS WORKS FINE**/

$albums = json_decode($fbfetch); /***I KNOW THIS WORKS FINE TOO**/



  <?php
     foreach ($albums->albums->data as $photo) {
        echo $photo->id . '<br>'; /**THIS WORKS**/
      }
   ?> 



foreach ($albums->albums->data->photos->data as $photo) { ?>


    <a href="<?php echo $photo['source']; ?>" title="<?php echo $photo['name']; ?>">
        <img src="<?php echo $photo['source']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $photo['name']; ?>" />

    </a> 


<?php } /**THIS DOESNT**/ ?>
```

I'm able to get information like "id" (which I don't need, by the way) from the "albums" "data" array on the 1st level, but that's as far as I go.
What I really need are the information in the "photos" array.

Any help with solving this problem would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
$fbfetch='{
  "albums": {
"data": [
  {
    "id": "1111111111111111111111111111", 
    "created_time": "2015-02-27T22:46:22+0000", 
    "photos": {
      "data": [
        {
          "name": "wedding", 
          "source": "https://scontent.xx.fbcdn.net/hphotos-xpf1/v/t1.0-9/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx", 
          "created_time": "2015-02-27T22:46:28+0000", 
          "id": "1111111111111111111111111111"
        }, 
        {
          "source": "https://scontent.xx.fbcdn.net/hphotos-xpf1/v/t1.0-9/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx", 
          "created_time": "2015-02-27T22:47:03+0000", 
          "id": "1111111111111111111111111111"
        }, 
        {
          "source": "https://fbcdn-sphotos-e-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-xfp1/v/t1.0-9/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx", 
          "created_time": "2015-02-27T22:47:10+0000", 
          "id": "1111111111111111111111111111"
        }, 
        {
          "name": "Shells", 
          "source": "https://fbcdn-sphotos-g-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-xap1/v/t1.0-9/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx", 
          "created_time": "2015-02-28T00:09:45+0000", 
          "id": "1111111111111111111111111111"
        }
      ], 
      "paging": {
        "cursors": {
          "before": "MTU5NjUyNDQzMzkxMDkwNQ==", 
          "after": "MTU5NjU0MDcwMzkwOTI3OA=="
        }
      }
    }
  }, 
  {
    "id": "1111111111111111666111111111", 
    "created_time": "2015-02-27T22:35:44+0000", 
    "photos": {
      "data": [
        {
          "source": "https://scontent.xx.fbcdn.net/hphotos-xpf1/v/t1.0-9/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx", 
          "created_time": "2015-02-27T22:35:46+0000", 
          "id": "111111111111111111111111333"
        }
      ], 
      "paging": {
        "cursors": {
          "before": "MTU5NjUyMjU1NzI0NDQyNg==", 
          "after": "MTU5NjUyMjU1NzI0NDQyNg=="
        }
      }
    }
  }
], 
"paging": {
  "cursors": {
    "after": "MTU5NjUyMjU1MDU3Nzc2MA==", 
    "before": "MTU5NjUyNDQwNzI0NDI0MQ=="
  }
}
}, 
"id": "76577536756346436343434"
 }';

 $albums = json_decode($fbfetch);

//print_r($albums); //For troubleshooting
 foreach ($albums->albums->data as $photos) { // I changed $photo to $photos here
    echo $photos->id . '<br>'; /**THIS WORKS**/
    //print_r($photos); //For troubleshooting
    foreach ($photos->photos->data as $photo) { ?>
        <?php //print_r($photo); //For troubleshooting ?>
        <a href="<?php echo $photo->source; ?>" title="<?php echo $photo->name; ?>">
            <img src="<?php echo $photo->source; ?>" alt="<?php echo $photo->name; ?>" />

        </a> 

    <?php }
  }
?>
```

For my purposes, I used your example JSON in string format. You'll notice a few print_r's that I used. They are now commented out. I just used them to help find the issue. The problem was in the final bit.

```
<a href="<?php echo $photo->source; ?>" title="<?php echo $photo->name; ?>">
<img src="<?php echo $photo->source; ?>" alt="<?php echo $photo->name; ?>" />
</a>
```

These were written out as arrays `$photo['source']` instead of objects `$photo->source`

(And, yes, I still used the embeded foreach)

I hope that's helpful! It ran perfectly for me. With a longer version of the following output:

```
1111111111111111111111111111<br>                <a href="https://scontent.xx.fbcdn.net/hphotos-xpf1/v/t1.0-9/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" title="wedding">
            <img src="https://scontent.xx.fbcdn.net/hphotos-xpf1/v/t1.0-9/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" alt="wedding" />

        </a> 

                    <a href="https://scontent.xx.fbcdn.net/hphotos-xpf1/v/t1.0-9/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" title="">
            <img src="https://scontent.xx.fbcdn.net/hphotos-xpf1/v/t1.0-9/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" alt="" />

        </a>
```

Comment: thanx alot @Button for the quick reply.. ..but the nested `foreach` didn't work. It just echoes an `"id"` once and stops. I think it's probably stopping at the inner `foreach` statement; and doesn't go back to finish the loop.

Comment: ..and, by the way, I removed a php close tag towards the end of your answer before trying it out.. please any further help would be appreciated

Comment: just to make sure, you did change the AS variable in the first for each from $photo to $photos so it wouldn't match the variable in the nested for each: `foreach ($albums->albums->data as $photos) { // I changed $photo to $photos here
    echo $photos->id . '<br>'; /**THIS WORKS**/
    foreach ($photos->photos->data as $photo) { ?>` Each foreach needs a unique AS variable.

Comment: yea, I did.. ..I nested the `foreach` statements exactly like you suggested. I'm just really confused why it isn't working. I'm tryna build this really cool gallery with "freewall".. ..and this little chunk of code is what's stalling me. it's just frustrating.

Comment: I reposted/edited the answer. Should be solved for you! Hope your project goes well!

Comment: IT WORKED! PERFECTLY!! :) ..just when I was about switching to flickr.. thanks a lot @Button.. ..you saved me. now I look at the facebook api differently. Thanks again.