# Can't deal with foreach levels with JSON decoding

Tags: php, json, facebook, foreach

I've been dealing with this problem around 5 hours, so I think that's time to ask here.

I'm retrieving data using Facebook Graph API and using JSON decoding to put it all together on a PHP.

Here's FB Graph:

```
{
  "feed": {
    "data": [
      {
        "message": "A file.",
        "id": "831407506978898_831408573645458",
        "attachments": {
          "data": [
            {
              "target": {
                "id": "1041214692589250",
                "url": "https://www.facebook.com/download/A-PDF-FILE.pdf"
              },
              "title": "Clase 01 - Vías de administración.pdf",
              "type": "file_upload",
              "url": "https://www.facebook.com/download/A-PDF-FILE.pdf"
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      {
        "picture": "https://fbcdn-photos-c-a.akamaihd.net/A-PHOTO.jpg",
        "message": "A photo.",
        "id": "831407506978898_831408496978799",
        "attachments": {
          "data": [
            {
              "description": "A photo.",
              "media": {
                "image": {
                  "height": 540,
                  "src": "https://fbcdn-photos-c-a.akamaihd.net/A-PHOTO.jpg",
                  "width": 720
                }
              },
              "target": {
                "id": "10207838160017396",
                "url": "https://fbcdn-photos-c-a.akamaihd.net/A-PHOTO.jpg"
              },
              "type": "photo",
              "url": "https://fbcdn-photos-c-a.akamaihd.net/A-PHOTO.jpg"
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      {
        "picture": "https://fbcdn-photos-c-a.akamaihd.net/A-PHOTO.jpg",
        "id": "831407506978898_831408450312137",
        "attachments": {
          "data": [
            {
              "media": {
                "image": {
                  "height": 540,
                  "src": "https://fbcdn-photos-c-a.akamaihd.net/A-PHOTO.jpg",
                  "width": 720
                }
              },
              "target": {
                "id": "10207838168217601",
                "url": "https://fbcdn-photos-c-a.akamaihd.net/A-PHOTO.jpg"
              },
              "type": "photo",
              "url": "https://fbcdn-photos-c-a.akamaihd.net/A-PHOTO.jpg"
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      {
        "message": "TEST",
        "id": "831407506978898_831407576978891"
      },
      {
        "id": "831407506978898_831407516978897"
      }
    ],
    "paging": {
      "previous": "https://graph.facebook.com/...alotofjunk"
    }
  },
  "id": "0000000000000"
}
```

And my PHP is the following one:

```
<?php

header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
$limit = 60; // The number of posts fetched
$access_token='TOKEN NUMBER';
$group_id = 'GROUPNUMBER';
$url1 = 'https://graph.facebook.com/'.$group_id.'?access_token='.$access_token;
$des = json_decode(file_get_contents($url1)) ;
$url2 = "https://graph.facebook.com/{$group_id}/feed?access_token={$access_token}";
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents($url2));
?>

 <?
$counter = 0;
foreach($data->data as $d) {
if($counter==$limit)
break;
?>

<? $themessage = (isset($d->message) ? $d->message : false); ?>
<? print $themessage ?>

<? $thepicture = (isset($d->picture) ? $d->picture : false); ?>
<? print "<img src=\"$thepicture\">" ?>

<!--THE PROBLEM IS FROM HERE.... -->
    <?
    $counter = 0;
    foreach($d->attachments->data as $d2) {
    if($counter==$limit)
    break;
    ?>

<? $attachments = (isset($d2->url) ? $d2->url  : false); ?>
<? print $attachments ?>

    <?
    }
    ?>
<!-- ...TO HERE -->    

<?
$counter++;
}
?>
```

I get a perfect output of $themessage and $thepicture, but I with $attachments I receive the following errors:

- Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$attachments in...
- Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in...
- Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in...

I've already read this: [Trouble with Facebook multi-level json php foreach loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28822981/trouble-with-facebook-multi-level-json-php-foreach-loop), but no luck.

How can I fix this?. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to be careful when you're chaining objects - especially in loops.  One empty object will bring down the whole show.  Try this:

```
$counter = 0;
if( isset( $d->attachments ) )
{
    foreach( $d->attachments->data as $d2 )
    {
        ....
    }
}
```

Comment: Worked fine!. Thanks bro!

Answer (score 1):

```
 Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$attachments in...
 Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in...
 Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in...
```

You're getting this error becoz you're missing feed object in your first loop 
   Here[DEMO](http://goo.gl/Qwu2Zs) 
**Replace**

```
foreach($data->data as $d) {
if($counter==$limit)
break;
?>
```

**With**

```
 foreach($data->feed->data as $d) {
    if($counter==$limit)
    break;
    ?>
```

Your JSON is in this format paste your JSON here [JSON Format Viewer](http://jsonviewer.stack.hu/) and check it [image: JSON DATA]

I tried your code i'm able to get url printed Here[DEMO](http://goo.gl/Qwu2Zs)

```
$data="Your JSON Here"
foreach($data->feed->data as $d) {
   $themessage = (isset($d->message) ? $d->message : false);
   print("\n".$themessage);
   $thepicture = (isset($d->picture) ? $d->picture : false);
   print("\n<img src='$thepicture'>");
   foreach($d->attachments->data as $d2) {
     $attachments = (isset($d2->url) ? $d2->url  : false);  
     print("\n".$attachments);
   }
}
```

*Side Note:* you're initailising $counter = 0; twice once inside loop 
and outside the loop its bad Even for $attachment, Its my opinion after looking your code for first time whatever you're reason be behind it